# Span with margin and paddings

Tags: html, css

I need to put two spans next to each other trying to obtain the effect in the pictures.

[image]

```
<li class="hello">
  <a href="#">
    <span>Hello</span> <span class="numbers">20</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Since span can't have margins, widths or padding I'm using inline-blocks:

```
li {
  height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left
}

li a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.numbers {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 18px;
  background:#A9A9A9
}
```

But this will push both "Hello" and "20" texts down a little bit and the gray background will be thrown up to the top (as showed below).

[image]

How can I achieve the effect as described in the first image?

**EDIT:** I've also included the relevant css for the `li` and `a` and [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eDAOp1mvsJy7jg9pfwYv?p=preview)

Comment: Can you make a demo? it's not enough styles you posted.

Comment: You may need to add the entire CSS including the li and a tag ... with this only code is working http://jsfiddle.net/6kujfb13/

Comment: I've included more css, see the edit

Comment: You already have answers change your demo will be [LIKE THIS](http://plnkr.co/edit/4hZEfFCb2bU0x5YF9hyC?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you have a value for the `line-height` of `44px`. With that an the `height` value on `numbers` you get a short background and offset text. You will need to set the value again for that span equal to his height:

```
.numbers {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  height:18px;
  line-height:18px; /*ADD THIS*/
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  background:#A9A9A9
}
```

```css
li {
  height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left
}

li a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  background:aqua;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.numbers {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  height:18px;
  line-height:18px;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  background:#A9A9A9
}
```

```html
<li class="hello">
  <a href="#">
    <span>Hello</span> <span class="numbers">20</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Not sure why but with this solution the bottom edge of the "20" background is cut for me. Meaning that there is no padding-botton, the grey background ends on the bottom line of the "20"

Comment: @Leonardo can you reproduce that issue= I've also changed the code on your plunker demo and works fine http://plnkr.co/edit/4hZEfFCb2bU0x5YF9hyC?p=preview

Comment: @Leonardo the problem can be you are using box-sizing border-box making the padding be included into the height like this http://plnkr.co/edit/51kNNhheh7tlaFZa2Y3Z?p=preview .... If that't the case you will need to increase the height like this http://plnkr.co/edit/EoUuf052SoswJLVyeixg?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Here you are :)

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
li a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.numbers {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #A9A9A9;  
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="hello">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Hello</span>  <span class="numbers">20</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hello">
    <a href="#">
      <span>World</span>  <span class="numbers">55</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.numbers {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #A9A9A9
}
li {
  background-color: lightblue;;
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="hello">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Hello</span>  <span class="numbers">20</span>
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is exact the same code of the OP ... also don't try to avoid the code necessary ...

Comment: I added the css missing to make it work so it's NOT the "exact the same code", but fine is you love downgrading valid answers. I Guess I'm getting use to it. I was going to add the code in a minute... anyway ty Vitorino for the edit.

Comment: Please read again the question the problem of the OP isn't the styles to acomplish the image ... he is getting an issue with the span background ...